# screen on my MacBook Pro goes completely black after I log in

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, fsck

I was fixing my Mac partition by rebooting and holding CMD+S and then typing

```
fsck -fy
```

It found some issues and (probably) fixed them.
Now when I boot into MacOS after some time the screen goes black and there is no way to do anything except put it to sleep. On waking up everything is normal.

I have quite some utility apps installed and one of them is probably misbehaving. How to troubleshoot this without trying to disable each one and then rebooting. It will take me 20 reboots to find the culprit. And how did that happen anyway? The fsck command was supposed to fix things, not screw them up :/

UPDATE:
[This is how the screen now looks like](http://cl.ly/image/3Z2A25431p0R) it has colorful line at the top.

I tried to see if anything is reported in Console, I tried twice:

screen went black at 11:04:06 and here is the log:

```
7/7/13 11:04:02.131 PM EvernoteHelper[908]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:04:02.752 PM SystemUIServer[662]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:04:03.426 PM Finder[663]: XtraFinder injected handler.
7/7/13 11:04:03.839 PM Bartender[864]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Butler.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:04:04.208 PM Bartender[864]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:04:06.006 PM login[939]: USER_PROCESS: 939 tty??
7/7/13 11:04:06.073 PM WindowServer[97]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4272dc0
7/7/13 11:04:06.122 PM WindowServer[97]: CGXMuxAcknowledge: Posting glitchless acknowledge
7/7/13 11:04:06.184 PM WindowServer[97]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4272dc0
7/7/13 11:04:06.185 PM WindowServer[97]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
7/7/13 11:04:06.223 PM Bartender[864]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:04:07.658 PM NotificationCenter[673]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:04:08.878 PM Default Folder X Helper[925]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:04:09.401 PM Butler[907]: loaded applications cache
7/7/13 11:04:10.018 PM Bartender[864]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Butler.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:04:11.081 PM ScopedBookmarkAgent[951]: CFURLCreateByResolvingBookmarkData failed with error [Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist."].
7/7/13 11:04:11.483 PM Found[911]: -[BLFAccountManager readAccountInfoFromDisk]():525 ASSERT FAILED:  couldn't resolve bookmark for /Volumes/REDSTAR/Cooking, error=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist."
7/7/13 11:04:11.765 PM Bowtie[920]: Started HTTP server on port 7455
```

Second try: went black at 11:14:35, log is here:

```
7/7/13 11:14:30.869 PM Butler[834]: cache: adding volumes...
7/7/13 11:14:30.875 PM Butler[834]: cache: adding applications...
7/7/13 11:14:30.876 PM Butler[834]: cache: adding scripts...
7/7/13 11:14:32.035 PM Adium[621]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:14:32.294 PM Google Drive[838]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:14:32.729 PM Butler[834]: cache: categorizing...
7/7/13 11:14:33.193 PM Bartender[796]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Dropbox.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:14:33.210 PM Bartender[796]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Butler.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:14:34.076 PM Butler[834]: updated abbreviations cache (enabled)
7/7/13 11:14:34.183 PM Butler[834]: still no need to poll iTunes
7/7/13 11:14:34.897 PM Butler[834]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:14:35.310 PM Dropbox[840]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:14:35.339 PM Found[839]: [BLFAccountManager(0x2a16ad0) handleCredentialStatus:]:270 error reading dir: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “Cooking” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x1a53930 {NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
), NSUnderlyingError=0x1a53910 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)", NSFilePath=/Volumes/REDSTAR/Cooking}
7/7/13 11:14:35.340 PM Found[839]: [BLFAccountManager(0x2a16ad0) handleCredentialStatus:]:270 error reading dir: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “Music” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x1a49320 {NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
), NSUnderlyingError=0x1a49300 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)", NSFilePath=/Volumes/REDSTAR/Music}
7/7/13 11:14:35.346 PM Found[839]: [BLFAccountManager(0x2a16ad0) handleCredentialStatus:]:270 error reading dir: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “Movies” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x1a495c0 {NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
), NSUnderlyingError=0x1a49480 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)", NSFilePath=/Volumes/REDSTAR/Movies}
7/7/13 11:14:35.347 PM Found[839]: [BLFAccountManager(0x2a16ad0) handleCredentialStatus:]:270 error reading dir: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “Tutorials” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x1a49d00 
7/7/13 11:14:35.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(974) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
7/7/13 11:14:35.815 PM Mailplane 3[608]: int main(int, char **) [Line 23] Use private HTTPCookieStorage
7/7/13 11:14:37.644 PM Mailplane 3[608]: +[UxPrivateHTTPCookieStorageSharedInstance install] [Line 50] Private HTTPCookieStorage has been installed.
7/7/13 11:14:38.138 PM Bartender[796]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/I Love Stars.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:14:38.140 PM Bartender[796]: warning: failed to get scripting definition from /Applications/Found.app; it may not be scriptable.
7/7/13 11:14:39.085 PM WindowServer[94]: kCGErrorNotImplemented: receive_notification: CPXSetEventFilter failed
7/7/13 11:14:39.088 PM Mailplane 3[608]: +[UxApplicationDataUpdate checkForUpdates:] [Line 35] Check data version (app=726, data=726)
7/7/13 11:14:39.163 PM I Love Stars[846]: Bartender Loaded
7/7/13 11:14:39.167 PM Found[839]: Bartender Loaded
```

Wonder what those "BLFAccountManager" file doesn't exists lines are .. but it's probably not related to the black screen issue. -- Answer: it's "Found app" sources which are currently not accessible.

UPDATE 2:

Sometimes the Preview windows [are black and missing PDF contents](http://cl.ly/image/0K123q340e1g)

More and more it seems to me that something in the Mac OS installation itself is faulty... I tried to repair permissions, didn't help... how can I repair the entire OS?

Comment: Can you look in the Console for reports right after it happens.

Comment: I updated the question with console output for two restarts... can't pinpoint the culprit :/

Comment: Now you can see what I see, = Bartender!!

Comment: I see that but I think that happens after the Dropbox[840]: Bartender Loaded

Comment: I already tried disabling Bartender at start and it didn't help....

Comment: You could not disable it ?   Did you try starting in safe mode without Bartender ?You did not disable the loading of the drivers just the log in mode.

Comment: I disabled Bartender in "Login items" and restarted. Didn't try in safe mode... will do it now...

Comment: In safe mode there was no problem! I then selected not to reopen my windows and now I don't have a problem in normal boot either... Before I always selected to reopen windows and I guess the saved state got messed up on disk repair. I should have tried a clean boot. I will now use the system and then try to reboot with opening windows a few times and let you know (tomorrow)... good night!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to make a clean reboot (choosing not to reopen currently running apps). The problem went away.

UPDATE: the problem came back and I discovered that the culprit was the gfxCardStatus app v2.2.1 .. after update I didn't have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the detailed question and information.

Based on your Console report it has something to do with the Bartender.

Since this is confirmed in Safe mode that there is a non apple driver conflict, lets try a simple fix following your partition repairs that could have corrupted the [permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1452).

Answer (score 0):

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
3. Turn on the computer.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears.
5. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
6. Release the keys.

After resetting NVRAM or PRAM, you may need to reconfigure your settings for speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, and time zone information. If issues persist, your Mac's logic board battery (not a portable Mac's rechargeable battery) may need to be replaced. The logic board battery helps retain NVRAM/PRAM settings when your computer is shut down. You can take your Mac to a Mac Genius or Apple Authorized Service Provider to replace the battery on the logic board.